# Swift: addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval for AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avaudioplayer, avplayer

I'm still trying to find a way that you can call an action when an `AVAudioPlayer` music file hits a specific second.

I know I could use the `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` method from the `AVPlayer` class, however I do not want to use `AVPlayer` since it does not use methods such as `playing()`, `stop()`, `numberOfLoops` etc since I'm currently using them

Is there an alternative method that `AVAudioPlayer` uses? If so, how would I do it when the `AVAudioPlayer` is into 20 seconds.

Comment: You could use Key-Value Observing to observe the value of the currentTime property then, check if it's at 20.

Answer (score 3):

I think your choices are to switch to using AVPlayer, or to "fake it" using an `NSTimer`, as suggested by Ashish, above, or some other method.

NSTimers aren't accurate beyond ~1/50th of a second (they run on the main thread and only fire when your app visits the run loop.)

You could try registering for KVO notification of the `currentTime` property of your `AVAudioPlayer`, and then detecting times that are within a specific second.

KVO notifications will probably be quite CPU-intensive, and may even cause the audio playing to stutter, since the KVO notice will fire every time the audio player changes the `currentTime` property, even if it's every 1/1000 of a second.

If you only need resolution within a second, and it doesn't have to be exact, NSTimer is the way to go.

Comment: Is there chance you could give me a sample code. Sorry, I'm a beginner and still trying to learn programming in iOS. I've used the code above but when I run it, it crashes and produces this console: [WSWSongChants.ComeOnYouWanderersViewController checkPlaybackTime]:

Comment: KVO code is a pain in the butt to write, and fairly costly to execute. I don't recommend it. Better to use an NSTimer, as Ashish suggested. What is your goal, and what are your requirements as far as accuracy?