# NSProgressIndicator with thumb

Tags: swift, macos

I'm working on music player app and I used `NSProgressIndicator` for the song timeline, how can I add a thumb to the `NSProgressIndicator`? I tried to add `NSSlider` but I can't hide the slider and show only the thumb, any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

It's actually not that easy to give you a complete answer without having more information about what you are trying to achieve.

The best thing to do would probably be to avoid the `NSProgressIndicator` entirely in favor of a `NSSlider`, which you mentioned in your question.

Then, you could setup a `periodicTimeObserverForInterval` (I assume you are using an `AVPlayer` to play your songs?) and change the slider value according to the reached point on the song timeline.

Finally, you should have a function that performs every time the slider value is changed by the user that changes the current position on the timeline according to the user input.

Here's how I would do it:

```swift
// Assuming you have a player instance of type AVPlayer in your ViewController
// var player = AVPlayer()

// Move the slider to reflect the current timeline position
func setupPlayer() {
    let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
    player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(interval, queue: Dispatch.main) { progress in
        let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
        
        if let duration = self.player.currentItem?.duration {
            // Get the number of seconds of the whole file
            let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            self.slider.value = Float(seconds / durationSeconds)
        }
    }
}

// Change the current timeline position according to the user input
func setupSlider() {
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(slider_valueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc func slider_valueChanged() {
    if let duration = player.currentItem?.duration {
        let totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        let value = Float64(slider.value) * totalSeconds
        let seekTime = CMTime(value: Int64(value), timescale: 1)
       
        player.seek(to: seekTime) { completedSeek in 
            // Add code here if you need to do something after the time was seeked
        }
    }
}
```

If you are instead using an `AVAudioPlayer` to play music, then I suggest
switching to `AVPlayer` or using an `NStimer`, due to the fact that `AVAudioPlayer` does not come with the `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` method, as [this answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31491938/17026411).

**Resources**

- [How to move the timeline according to the slider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HX1aYzaHex8&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj&index=18)
- [How to move the slider according to the timeline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwI9YF6i3DM&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj&index=19)
- [AVPlayer (and much more) tutorial by Let's Build That App](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj)
- [AVPlayer on the official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer)

Comment: Have you tried your code? It is missing `)` and `}` and `slider` is a `UISlider` instead of a `NSSlider`.

Comment: What is the point of saying "My answer"? Obviously this is your answer; it is by you and it is in the Answer field.